# Hyperledger Fabric: How can a user be expected to have ca certificates of other organizations when trying to invoke chaincode?

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric

When a user invokes chaincode, they need to pass peer addresses on which chaincode will be evaluated for endoresement. If TLS is enabled then the user also needs to have the CA certs of the peers above. Example, lets say there are three organizations A, B, C. The endorsement policy requires an endorsement from each of these organizations. A user in A's organization wants to invoke the chaincode. They will need to run the [peer chaincode invoke](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/commands/peerchaincode.html#peer-chaincode-invoke) passing in peer addresses such that a peer from each org is included. That is Ok. But if TLS is enabled, then the user is also expected to include the TLS CA Cert of each organization (using the `--tlsRootCertFiles` option), otherwise the call fails. How is this reasonable? And how can the user be expected to have the TLS CA Cert of other organizations? In practice, how will this be acquired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is this reasonable?

To give background behind why this question was asked, when `peer chaincode invoke` is called it needs to be passed a CORE_PEER_ADDRESS otherwise there is an error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x60 pc=0x110fddc]

goroutine 1 [running]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common.NewPeerClientForAddress(0x7ffd955fe783, 0x9, 0x7ffd955fe7a0, 0x10, 0x8fb52c, 0x9e8745, 0x14848a7)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/common/peerclient.go:44 +0x8c
```

we thought that `peer chaincode invoke` simply submits a request to the peer given in CORE_PEER_ADDRESS and the actual act of invoking the chaincode on the peers given in `--peerAddresses` is done by the peer in CORE_PEER_ADDRESS. If that were the case then the client executing `peer chaincode invoke` should not have to carry TLS CA certs of the peers given in `--peerAddresses`. *However, that is not true*. The client executing `peer chaincode invoke` does invoke the chaincode on the `--peerAddresses`. If TLS is enabled on the peers (`CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true` when peer was started), then the client will require TLS CA certs of the peers in `--peerAddresses` for TLS authentication to succeed.

> And how can the user be expected to have the TLS CA Cert of other organizations? In practice, how will this be acquired?

One way to obtain the TLS CA Certs = certs of the authorities who issued other organizations their TLS certs, is using the [discover](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/discovery-cli.html) CLI as follows:

```
/etc/hyperledger/bin/discover --peerTLSCA my-ca-chain.pem  --userKey msp/keystore/user-myorg.key  --userCert msp/signcerts/user-myorg.pem  --MSP myorgMSP  --tlsCert user-myorg-tls-client.pem  --tlsKey user-myorg-tls-client.key config --server peer1-myorg:7051 --channel mychannel > discover.json
```

The certs in `discover.json` are base64 encoded. So they need to be base64 decoded and if there are intermediate certs, then these need to come before the root certs in the chain file.

Example:

```
cat discover.json | jq .msps.cvsMSP.tls_root_certs[0] | sed "s/\"//g" | base64 --decode > rca-cvs.pem
cat discover.json | jq .msps.cvsMSP.tls_intermediate_certs[0] | sed "s/\"//g" | base64 --decode > ica-cvs.pem
cat ica-cvs.pem rca-cvs.pem > cvs-ca-chain.pem
```

The discover CLI is part of the binaries that get downloaded when running Fabric install [script](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/install.html).

Answer (score 0):

this is not different from issuing certificates for web service: either you trust a thirdparty provider to exchange certificate, or exchange directly with counter-party.

Fabric is a permissioned blockchain, and there *is* a certain level of trust to begin with. Otherwise, you'll never know who you are transacting with, like in bitcoin of ethereum, which is addressing a different use case.